# Redirect Traffic in Hotspot Network

Tags: android, redirect, proxy, iptables, netsh

*I'm not sure if this is possible*, I'm trying to redirect traffic from a mobile app that is connected to the internet through a hotspot wifi from my laptop. The app is Sending requests to a cloud server, and the idea is that the traffic should first go through a proxy that is listening to a local port in my laptop, as per this rough sketch:

[image]

I believe this could **maybe** be solved using `iptables`, but I'm using Windows, I've looked into `netsh` but so far I haven't found a command (such as `portproxy`) that suits my needs, partly because I don't know if this is possible at all. I'm purposefully being a bit general here but if there's any questions we can go more in-depth.

Can someone give me a hint here?

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I believe I was close to a solution but we decided it would be too great of a cost to spend hours trying to solve this scenario. Instead we convinced the customer to release a build of the app which pointed directly to the proxy.